# How do you use the 'system' command in C++?

Tags: c++, console, game-loop

I'm exploring C++ and trying to make a simple loop that will clear screen. I know in C, the 'system' command syntax:

system("cls");

will make the command terminal clear the screen. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char choice = 'a';
    while(choice != 'x')
    {
        cout << "What is the variable?" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        system("cls");
    }

    cout << choice << " is the variable" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is my error message:

```
error: 'system' was not declared in this scope
```

Do I need to include a library to use system in C++?  I cannot find 'system' in the index of my books, so this may not be C++'s appropriate syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/
I like this artcle because it shows the few different ways that are able to get the job done. I would personally use the last option created by setting all the characters to space then move the curser to 0,0

Answer (score 2):

As [can be found easily](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) the `system` function is defined in the `<cstdlib>` header. Note also that using this function isn't a good programming practice.